# Python tornado AsyncHTTPClient 599

Tags: python, tornado

I try to send async PUT request with AsyncHTTPClient, but tornado return HTTP 599 error before request_timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem by write body="" to request:

```
 req = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url,
                                     method="PUT",
                                     request_timeout=10,
                                     headers=headers,
                                     **body=""**)
```

Tornado can't send put request with empty body.

Comment: Why would you want to sent a `PUT` request with empty body? The purpose of `PUT` is to send a resource to the service.

Comment: I use REST API of Yandex Drive. I create folder by PUT request with empty body